# compareTo for Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, comparator

I have a class with a set of fields:

```
class T {
int timestamp;
String name;
}
```

with autogenerated hashcode/equals/compareTo based on these fields.
I need to add another one field `Map<String, Object> parameters`
It is not difficult to inmplement hashCode/equals for it, but I'm a bit stuck with compareTo:

1. if timestamp and name are the same, it is not important what order is for two instances of T class, but I want it to satisfy compareTo contract (for example, not just "return 1").
2. I want it to be in sync with equals, so I can't just skip parameters field in compareTo (in this case it could be a different result if we use HashSet or TreeSet to store items).
3. So I don't care about an order of if two first fields are equal, but want to avoid weird issues like mentioned in 2)

I was not able to invent any compareTo for this field to satisfy these requirements if equals compares the whole maps. Probably I can use something like comparison by hashcode in equals and compareTo, but it looks very weird for me.
Are there any options here?

Comment: Maybe compare timestamp first ; if equal, compare  name, if equal take parameters keySet sorted on their name, and compare that ?

Comment: What about adding yet another surrogate field, purely for comparison, sth like 'position'? On the other hand, if you want it to be in sync with equals, then you'll have to make sure this fields is same for two equal 'parameters' maps

Comment: @Jeremy Grand, in this case we have maps with the same keys but different values compareTo will return 0, while equals is false.

Comment: I think you will always get this problem if your class implements `Comparable` and your `equals` relies on field not implementing this interface

Comment: @dbf I didn't want to go that long into a simple comment, you could take the whole EntrySet, sorted alphabetically on keys and compare, for each entry, the key then the value.

Comment: @JeremyGrand , ah, I see. But value is an object - I can't compare them.

Comment: @dbf yes, but then, as Stefan pointed out, trying to compare non-comparable Object will always lead to this kind of issue. You could try to compare at least compare the Object's hashcode even if it does not fully respect the contract.